# Conditional operator in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, conditional-operator

I am trying to conditionally execute two different mongoose operators but it just return no error and doesn't work to update the document.

My Schema:

```js
const CartSchema: Schema<Document<ICart>> = new Schema({
    clientID: { type: String, required: true },
    sourceID: { type: String, required: true },
    items: { type: Array },
    source: { type: String, required: true },
}, { collection: "carts", timestamps: true });
```

The way I am trying to implement that:

```js
await CartModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { sourceID: clientID, 'items.id': Types.ObjectId(itemID) }, 
    { 
         $cond: { 
              if: {
                  $eq: 1,
              },
              then: { $pull: { 'items.$.id': Types.ObjectId(itemID) }},
              else: { $inc: { 'items.$.amount': -1 }},
         }
    }, 
    { new: true }
).lean({ virtuals: true })
```

And I also tried to have this kind of query: `{ sourceID: clientID }` but it didn't help. I thought maybe I could not find the element and it just silently pass through.

The main idea here of what I am gonna do is - have a conditional mongoose request where I'll either remove the object from the array if the current value in the field `amount` is equal to `1`, or decrement the value to `-1`.

Comment: you cant mix update operators with aggregate operators, if you want something that you cant do with common update operators, use update with pipeline and aggregate operators only.
If you need `$cond` then use `[...]` to make it a pipeline update, find a method that accept pipelines as arguments in mongoose or send runCommand(update command), replace `pull` with `$filter` and inc with $add 1. See documentation about pipeline updates

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the `$cond` operator works only in the `aggregation` framework but in my Atlas tier I cannot check if the query works properly, but I suppose it should look something like this:

```js
           await CartModel.aggregate([
                { $match: {
                    sourceID: clientID, 
                    'items.id': Types.ObjectId(itemID)
                    }
                }, 
                { 
                    $cond: { 
                        if: {
                            $eq: 1,
                        },
                        then: { $pull: { 'items.$.id': Types.ObjectId(itemID) }},
                        else: { $inc: { 'items.$.amount': -1 }},
                    }
                }
            ])
```